# How can I query for completed releases using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I can retrieve a list of releases on Azure Devops using

`var releases = await releaseClient.GetReleasesAsync(project: projectName, definitionId: releaseDefinition.Id);`

The releases all show the Status Active. But in the devops portal I see that some have pending tasks (Approval). How can I check that all stages ( environments ) have completed?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- How can I check that all stages have completed?

`GetReleasesAsync` will lists all the release status (abandoned,active,draft,undefined). If you want to check the stages status for each release. You probably need to look into the [Release Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#releaseenvironment) for each specific release.

After you get all the releases by `GetReleasesAsync(ProjectName, releaseDefinitionId)` You can then use `GetReleaseAsync(string projectName, int releaseId)` to get the detailed release Environments information for the specific release by release id. If a stage is pending for approval, the status will show "inProgress"

For Below simple example.

```
 var releases =  releaseClient.GetReleasesAsync(Project, releaseDefinitionId).Result;

 foreach(var release in releases)
 {
     var releaseResult = releaseClient.GetReleaseAsync(Project, release.Id).Result;

     foreach (var en in releaseResult.Environments)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(en.Status);
     }
  }
```